# Get arrays from a file then loop it

Tags: php, arrays, file, get

Try to get arrays from a file like...

**data.txt**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 288
    [1] => 287
    [2] => 173
)
```

**my.php**

```
$data = file('data.txt');

foreach ($data as $id) {
    echo $id." - ";
}
```

Why its echo all arrays back ? like data.txt

Why not echo like 288 - 287 - 173 ?

**CLOSED : I using JSON now**

Comment: Does your `data.txt` file actually contain the result of `print_r`?

Comment: yes :( how can i do it ?

Comment: @l2aelba you can write data into `serialize` format.When you read data then `unserialize`

Comment: How are you dumping data to data.txt file ? And why is it in this format ? Any specific reason ?

Comment: fail foreach function ? or what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When saving your data, get the string representation using `serialize`:

```
$str = serialize($arr);
```

You can then use `unserialize` to decode your array:

```
$arr = unserialize(file(data.txt));
```

Comment: +1, BTW, I'd use `json_encode/json_decode` because saved data will be flexible enough to be used with other languages.

Comment: @PLB I thought about that, but while `json_encode` is good enough for numeric, string literals, it fails for more complex data types.

Comment: what do you mean in failure?

Comment: @PLB Unless your object is an instance of a class that implements `JSONSerializable`, `json_encode` naively uses the result of casting the object as a string, which could be lossy.

Comment: @PLB Try `serialize/unserialize` and `json_encode/decode` on an array containing a string, a number and a `DateTime` instance to see what I mean.

Comment: @l2aelba It will work in most cases but Asad is right at some point some data may be lost. However with simple data, I'd advise you to go with json.

Comment: Better to use JSON , coz i will get data with jQuery after that also.

Comment: @l2aelba Whatever floats your boat :) Just remember, you are restricted to string and numeric data types in your array.

Answer (score 2):

Your method loads the data in data.txt as a string, and php will not parse it as code. Try

```
$data = eval(file(data.txt));
```

See more on eval here: [PHP manual on eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Also note that the syntax in data.txt is invalid. You want:

```
array(288, 287, 173);
```

PHP will automatically create the indexes as needed.

On a second note, this is probably not the best way to go about it. Not knowing what you aim to achieve here, but would it not be better to just have the array set in your php file?

Comment: `eval` on a txt file  ... really ?

Comment: if my syntax look like i posted ?